# Why does TempFileCollection throw exception at AddExtension("tmp")?

Tags: c#, .net

Does anyone know why the code below throws System.ArgumentException?

```
using (var tfc = new TempFileCollection())
{                
    var fn = tfc.AddExtension("tmp");
    Console.WriteLine(fn);
}
```

Here is exact exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: The file name 'C:\Users\pczapla\AppData\Local\Temp\iqulrqva.tmp' was already in the collection.
Parameter name: fileName.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little Reflector action reveals the following interesting snippet in `TempFileCollection`:

```
new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.AllAccess, basePath).Demand();
path = this.basePath + ".tmp";
using (new FileStream(path, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
{
}
flag = true;
...
this.files.Add(path, this.keepFiles);
```

This is in `TempFileCollection.EnsureTempNameCreated`, which is called by `TempFileCollection.BasePath`, which is called by `TempFileCollection.AddExtension`. I guess the placeholder uses ".tmp" so you cannot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the first time you call the `AddExtension` method, it will automatically add a filename with the "tmp" extension to the collection before then trying to add the filename with your specified extension.

So if you specify "tmp" as the extension then it will try to add the same file twice, causing the exception.

```
using (var tfc = new TempFileCollection())
{
    var foo = tfc.AddExtension("foo");
    var bar = tfc.AddExtension("bar");

    foreach (var f in tfc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(f);
    }
}
```

The above code will generate the following output. Notice that it includes a filename with the "tmp" extension that we didn't explicitly add.

```
C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\jmat4jqg.tmp
C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\jmat4jqg.bar
C:\Users\Luke\AppData\Local\Temp\jmat4jqg.foo
```